# How do you disable users in AAD?

Tags: security, azure-active-directory

I've got a user who signs in at 12 PM to an asset exchange using AAD for authentication.  At 1 PM I discover that they're violating the exchange rules and I go into the Azure Portal and block the sign-ins for that user.  As nearly as I can tell, this user's token is good for at least another hour.  Is there any way to force a User out of the system without deleting his account?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the user's ability to sign in and access services in the Azure Portal.  This will disable the user from signing in again or exchanging their refresh token for a new tokens.

Keep in mind, the user will still be able to access the resource as long as their access token is still valid (lifetime of 1 hour).  To combat this, you can reduce the time of access tokens. [Steps of how to change the lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes).